# Is the dif or patch adder for Delphi IDE, ie if someone makes patch and I want to add it to my project automatically?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal

Is there DIFF plugin availaple for Delphi? I need simple add diff or patch file to my project, replaceing the porject code, that was changed in the patch, but keeping also the old one incase of falling back to old file without the patch.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, please re-edit the question and title, ... a diff doesn't depend on the programming language, ... AND add an example.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a version control system to check the files into, you can use the version control tools to maintain the ability to store differences and merge.  [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) along with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) seems to be a very popular (and open source) method of doing just this.  There are plenty of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370518/how-do-i-start-with-working-sub-version-delphi) of integration into the IDE.

The history tab in the IDE works well too, if you are the only one working on the file.  If this is the case I would set the history rather high, and use the [GExperts](http://gexperts.org/) project backup wizard to make "checkpoint" backups.

A fantastic windows based diff/merge utility that I strongly recommend is [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), which also happens to be written in Delphi.  :)

Answer (score 1):

[Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/)
It's an excellent differencing tool for source files without needing Delphi.
Bri

Answer (score 1):

Use a version control system, like [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is asking something like the diff/patch utils from [GNUWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) tools.
You get a patch file and apply it to the code base.